# MERGE statement with two WHEN MATCHED

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

I have this MERGE statement working fine:

```
MERGE INTO product_replenishment PR
USING ( SELECT * FROM traxs_temp..__MinMaxImport WHERE session_id = @session_id ) T
    ON T._product = PR.product AND T._branch_no = PR.branch_no
WHEN MATCHED AND T._stock_warehouse IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE SET
        date_time_updated = GETDATE(),
        user_no_updated = @user_no,
        stock_warehouse = T._stock_warehouse
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND T._stock_warehouse IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT 
        (date_time_created,
        date_time_updated,
        user_no_created,
        user_no_updated,
        branch_no,
        product,
        stock_warehouse,
        archive) 
    VALUES 
        (GETDATE(),
        GETDATE(),
        @user_no,
        @user_no,
        T._branch_no,
        T._product,
        T._stock_warehouse,
        0);
```

I want to add another `WHEN MATCHED` statement like this:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND T._stock_warehouse IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE SET
        date_time_updated = GETDATE(),
        user_no_updated = @user_no,
        stock_warehouse = T._stock_warehouse
WHEN MATCHED AND T._stock_warehouse IS NULL THEN
    UPDATE SET
        date_time_updated = GETDATE(),
        user_no_updated = @user_no,
        archive = 1
```

But I get an error: `An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement.`

Is it impossible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET stock_warehouse = COALESCE(T._stock_warehouse, stock_warehouse), archive = CASE WHEN T._stock_warehouse IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE archive END, ...other identical updates...`

Comment: Also, please [read this article about `MERGE`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) - particularly the parts about race conditions. `MERGE` may look like one nice, tight, atomic operation but it actually is processed as multiple behind the scenes unless you protect it correctly.

Comment: I get that and I added `WITH (HOLDLOCK)`. Is there any reliable way to do what I want without using `MERGE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general case can be emulated using `CASE` expressions as I've shown in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61137048/521799), or in [this blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/04/10/the-many-flavours-of-the-arcane-sql-merge-statement/). But your case is more specific, because the difference between the two clauses is simpler than the general case. You can combine them into one clause:

```sql
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  -- These are always updated the same way, regardless of the WHEN MATCHED AND predicate
  date_time_updated = GETDATE(),
  user_no_updated = @user_no,

  -- These depend on the relevant WHEN MATCHED AND predicate, so use CASE
  stock_warehouse = CASE 
    WHEN T._stock_warehouse IS NOT NULL THEN T._stock_warehouse 
    ELSE stock_warehouse
  END,
  archive = CASE WHEN T._stock_warehouse IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE archive END
```